How to make Popper.el stop moving cursor to popped buffer?
I've bind a shell-command (via async-shell-command) which I'm executing frequently.

I really like popper.el putting the result buffer (from async-shell-command) in nice position.
However, (only this specific command) I don't like popper.el moving my cursor to "popped" result buffer.
Reason is that I'm frequently running this command, and moving cursor is taking me out of my brain-processing flow.

Question: How to modifty my config such that my cursor won't jump to new popped (popper) buffer?
;;;;;;; config ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(setq package-archives
      '(("elpa"    . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"  )
        )))
(package-initialize)

(use-package popper
  :ensure t ; or :straight t
  :bind (("C-`"   . popper-toggle)
         ("M-`"   . popper-cycle)
         ("C-M-`" . popper-toggle-type))
  :init
  (setq popper-reference-buffers
        '("\\*Messages\\*"
          "Output\\*$"
          "\\*Async Shell Command\\*"
          help-mode
          compilation-mode))
  (popper-mode +1)
  (popper-echo-mode +1))                ; For echo area hints
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(popper-mode -1)
(async-shell-command "ls /tmp/")  ;; cursor doesn't result buffer

(popper-mode +1)
(async-shell-command "ls /tmp/") ;; cursor jumps to result buffer





I suggest use shackle https://depp.brause.cc/shackle/ to control buffer display and (setq popper-display-control nil) as https://github.com/karthink/popper?tab=readme-ov-file#popup-placement-controlled-using-display-buffer-alist-or-shackleel.
